# How to set up PHPUnit for an Apigility ZF2 application with multiple versions?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, phpunit, laminas-api-tools

The `phpunit.xml` for a common ZF2 application with the common folders structure

```
...
/phpunit
/phpunit/phpunit.xml
/module
/module/Application
/module/ModuleFoo
/module/ModuleBar
...
```

can be defined as follows:

```
<phpunit>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="modules">
            <directory>../modules/Application/tests</directory>
            <directory>../modules/ModuleFoo/tests</directory>
            <directory>../modules/ModuleBar/tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Now I'm writing an Apigility driven REST API application, that will have multiple verisions in the future.

```
...
/phpunit
/phpunit/phpunit.xml
/module
/module/Application
/module/ModuleBuzApi
/module/ModuleBuzApi/V1
/module/ModuleBuzApi/V2
...
/module/ModuleBuzApi/Vn
...
```

I can define a test suite for every version, but then I'll have to copy&paste it for every new version. Is there a more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use wildcard?

For instance:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="modules">
        <directory>../modules/*/tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! As I know wildcards don't work fot test suite directories paths. But anyway -- it's not, what I need, since (if it works) then all versions will be tested at once. It must be possible to test versions separately.

Comment: Actually I was using `<directory>*Test</directory>` and it's working. 
Although if you want to execute (and name) them separately, I don't think it's possible to achieve automatically :/